# Windows 7 Turtle Beach X12 Microphone Problems

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, microphone

I have my turtle beaches plugged in and I can hear everything fine, it has worked before but for some reason when I view my recording devices it tells me nothing is there. IDK what drives to look for or anything like that I've tried googling but `montego` driver that most articles speak of. Is there a way to detect my mic or something?

The model is X12

My PC is Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Wired? Pink jack plugged in? Why would headphones need a driver? Are they USB?

Comment: it's USB, but I also need my green sound and pink mic part plugged in.

Comment: That doesn't actually make sense to me... If they are USB why do they need the green and pink? What happens if you disconnect the USB and use the pink and green only?

Comment: I get no sound. If i get rid of the green wire, the sound goes through my speakers. pink is mic.

Comment: Doesn't the px12 have a USB sound enhancer type device?